# Get parameter broken

Tags: javascript, getparameter

I have an issue with a get parameter function, I have 2 parameters `engTrackid` and `eng`. The parameters are added automatically to my URL links. I need to grab the `eng` parameter, but instead it grabs the `engTrackId` and breaks it.

I.e. `www.test.com/reg?engTrackid=123&eng=456`

My page has a registration page, after submit, it should pass `eng` value to the TY page, but it looks like this:

`www.test.com/ty?eng=rackid=456` instead of `www.test.com/ty?eng=456`

This is the function I'm using:

```js
function getUrlVars() {
  var vars = {};
  var parts = window.location.href.replace(
    /[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,
    function(m,key,value) {
      vars[key] = value;
    }
  );
  return vars;
}
var elq = getUrlVars()["elq"];
```

As a note, I can't change the order of the parameters :(

Comment: In your code you are trying to get `["elq"]`. Is it right?

Comment: Can you fix the problem with the registration page instead of trying to fix the url caused by the previous page?

Answer (score 0):

You can change this:

elq = getUrlVars()["elq"];

to this:

```
 eng = getUrlVars()["eng"];
```

in order to get the right "eng" parameter value. Also once you call `getUrlVars()` you can get its value by reading

```
vars.eng
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `getUrlVars()` function works well for standard compliant URLs such as  www.test.com/reg?engTrackid=123&eng=456.

To correctly read the get parameters of a 'broken' URLs such as www.test.com/ty?eng=rackid=456 you need to modify the regex within that function:

```js
function getUrlVars(href) {
  var vars = {};
  href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, function(m, key, value) {
    vars[key] = value;
  });
  return vars;
}

function getBrokenUrlVars(href) {
  var vars = {};
  href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=(?:[^=&]*=)*([^&]*)/gi, function(m, key, value) {
    vars[key] = value;
  });
  return vars;
}

href1 = "www.test.com/reg?engTrackid=123&eng=456";
href2 = "www.test.com/ty?eng=rackid=456";

console.log(getUrlVars(href1)); // {"engTrackid": "123", "eng": "456"}
console.log(getUrlVars(href2)); // {"eng": "rackid=456"}

console.log(getBrokenUrlVars(href1)); // {"engTrackid": "123", "eng": "456"}
console.log(getBrokenUrlVars(href2)); // {"eng": "456"}
```

If you can, try to fix the problem leading to the broken URLs though!

Comment: Thank you! I'll try that and get back in case it didn't work! :) Thank you!... and yes, I used to have elq as the parameter but I had to switch to eng :)